How to explicitly kill flutter app embedded on web?
I have done the implementation of flutter embed in react and am initializing the app using engineInitializer?.initializeEngine, How can I kill this app when needed?
This is what I have referred:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization
https://github.com/p-mazhnik/flutter-embedding
